# Embedded Google Analytics JS API integration issues

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics into the back-end of a website I'm developing and I'm almost there, except for a few last tweaks.
Who can help me?

1) At the moment the client first sees the Google Authentication button before he can continue. This is because the rights have to be checked etc. Obviously.
However: the integration is in the back-end, so I know this user is allowed to see the data (at least on my side), even more: I know the Google account and password for that user. Translated: for everyone with access to the back-end the same Google account may be used. How can I make sure the request is done via this specific user? So is there a way I can do the login automatically without having the consent and log-in part? My back-end is PHP.

2) For some reason Google Analytics sometimes messes up the language settings and even though I'm Dutch it shows the embedded graphs in English.
Is there a parameter or something I can set to push the language?

3) My worldwide GEO map works fine, but my 'zoomed' in map shows the legend correctly, but doesn't show the cities themselves...
Any ideas? This is the code:

```
                  var dataCity = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                query: {
                  ids: ga_report_ids,
                  metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                  dimensions: 'ga:city',
                  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                  'end-date': 'today',
                  filters: 'ga:country==Belgium',
                  sort: '-ga:sessions'
                },
                chart: {
                  container: 'chart-cities',
                  type: 'GEO',
                  options: {
                    width: '420px',
                    'region': 'BE',
                    'dataMode': 'markers'
                  }
                }
              });
```

4) I'd also like some real time statistics on the panel. I've requested the Beta access and implemented the right dimensions and metrics, but I only get errors, no data... Any ideas?

Comment: <<I know the Google account and password for that user.>>  If you know this, then why even make the person do client-side authentication?  It seems you should be able to make use of the Google Analytics API with your php.

Comment: <<'zoomed' in map shows the legend correctly, but doesn't show the cities themselves.>>  You might want to try getting Latitude/Longitude as dimensions as well.  I think the marker mode may need this.